# Save BSON document in a readable format

Tags: c#

I have the following code which saves the collection to a text file.

```
 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
                var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("clicks");


                var r = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                r.ForEach(d => builder.Append(d.ToString() + "\n"));


                File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, builder.ToString());

        }
```

Although, the code saves all the data in this format:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e86f83135beb07942fac1d"), "username" : "fombef", "time" : ISODate("2016-03-15T21:24:35.378Z") etc..

Is there any way to make this data readable and saved in a formal way like this example:

fombef, 2016-03-15T21:24:35.378Z

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the Bson to a class using JSON.Net create a class that can hold your data to serialize:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}

serializer.Deserialize<Myclass>(bson);
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeFromBson.htm

Comment: I did not understand